# How to conditionally show a WebControl?

Tags: publishing-site, asp.net, conditional

I'm quiet new to Sharepoint and ASP.NET and by far not an coding expert. I actually have a quiet simple question

I'm building a custom publishing site-layout with several WebControls (RichImageField,RichHtmlField,SummaryLinkFieldControl,Userfield ...). Each WebControl is wrapped in a `<div>`, some of them get extra markup like a `<h3>` (Title) or `<span>` (some description).

How do I output some code based on the condition of a WebControl (= field has Content or field has no content).

For Example: I want to output the following snippet, only if "TestField" has content.

```
<div class="wrapper>
    <h3>Test Field</h3>
    <PublishingWebControls:SummaryLinkFieldControl runat="server" FieldName="TestField" />
</div>
```

Otherwise do not output anything. (I don't want to hide it via JS or CSS)

In PHP I simply can do:

```
<?php if (isset($foo)) {
    echo $foo;
} ?>
```

or

```
<?php if !empty($foo)) {
    echo $foo;
} ?>
```

Is there something like this in ASP?

Maybe I'm totally wrong and has to change the output of an WebControl itself somewhere else. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Cant you use JavaScript and hide the HTML element if empty?

Comment: Of course i can. But i actually prefer to hide these kind of empty content server-side. Mainly because of performance issues, but also for accessibility reasons. Someone who turned of JavaScript should not see this content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create a custom WebControl of your own which you wrap around each of the controls in the Page Layout that should be hidden if empty.

You could have a property on your custom control that will be containing the ID of the control it should hide if the control is empty.

Example:

```
<MyControls:HideWhenEmpty runat="server" ID="HideWhenEmpty1" ControlToHideIfEmpty="SummaryLinkFieldControl1">
    <div class="wrapper>
        <h3>Test Field</h3>
        <PublishingWebControls:SummaryLinkFieldControl runat="server" ID="SummaryLinkFieldControl1" FieldName="TestField" />
    </div>
</MyControls:HideWhenEmpty>
```

In your custom control's `OnPreRender` event you check if the control with the ID of the `ControlToHideIfEmpty` property is empty. You `return false;` (<- this will stop the rendering of `HideWhenEmpty1` and everything within it) if it is empty and `return true;` if it is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try this. Do you maybe have tutorial which you can recommend of how to create a custom WebControl? One last question: There is no standard Sharepoint/ASP.NET solution for there kind of scenarios? Is there any (other) best practice solution if I want to wrap a WebControl in custom HTML?